# Lucene Index History / Last File Indexed

Tags: java, lucene, indexing

Is there a way to find out the last Lucene Document that was entered in a Lucene index? E.g. does Lucene keep track of the history somehow or can I somehow extract the order of Files (Document) that have been added to an index?

Background: I want to build a very large index with millions of document that takes a few days to run. I would like to have an index implementation that detects what the last file was that was added and continue at this position when restarted again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no.  The closest you would get would be to get the highest doc id from the index.  If you just start adding documents to an empty index, and nothing gets deleted or updates or any such, then it might even work.  There are no guarantees of doc ids being assigned in order though.

If you need to know the order in which docs are added. you should add a field that handles that.  Either a date/time stored index time, or sequential id would serve nicely.  Though it sounds a bit like even that would be overkill, and you just need to store an identifier to identify the source document to resume from.  In that case, store that one id where ever.  In lucene, in a database, in a txt file, a serialized string.  Whatever makes you happy.

Comment: Makes sense, I stored the last id that was indexed from my collection and that seems to work nice. I actually store every id so that I do not have to wonder which one might be double and the runtime performance is quite good...